# WSL2 - Resize/Extend Disk

Tags: windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Windows 10 with Docker on WSL2 (With Ubuntu20 Linux Subsystem).
I originally got all this installed on my C: disk, which was a 256Go Drive.

I've change my drive for a 1To drive and I extended my system partition. In windows all is fine but I still encounter "no space left on device" issues inside WSL2.

How can I resize my Linux disk so I can use more space?

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb       ext4      251G   18G  221G   8% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     4.9G  400M  4.5G   9% /mnt/wsl
tools          9p        931G  269G  663G  29% /init
none           devtmpfs  4.9G     0  4.9G   0% /dev
none           tmpfs     4.9G  8.0K  4.9G   1% /run
none           tmpfs     4.9G     0  4.9G   0% /run/lock
none           tmpfs     4.9G     0  4.9G   0% /run/shm
none           tmpfs     4.9G     0  4.9G   0% /run/user
tmpfs          tmpfs     4.9G     0  4.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
C:\            9p        931G  269G  663G  29% /mnt/c
D:\            9p        466G  6.6G  460G   2% /mnt/d
E:\            9p        1.9T   85G  1.8T   5% /mnt/e
/dev/sdd       ext4      251G  164G   76G  69% /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/isocache
none           tmpfs     4.9G   12K  4.9G   1% /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/shared-sockets/host-services
/dev/sdc       ext4      251G  130M  239G   1% /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/docker-desktop-proxy
/dev/loop0     iso9660   396M  396M     0 100% /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools
```

Comment: The docs may have, at one point, talked to resizing...but they don't do it now.